# Efficient structure for storing pareto optimal solutions

Tags: c++, optimization, data-structures

I am trying to solve problem which requires storing pareto optimal solutions during calculation. I will call set of pareto optimal solutions a Bag.

So far I had only two criteria, which allowed for quite efficient solution based on an array in which elements were sorted in descending order according to the first criterion and ascending according to the second criterion. An example of such an array would be:

```
[(100, 0), (50, 1), (-10, 3)]
```

(about pareto optimality - [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization))

Recently however I found out that I need to add third criterion and for such an extension the above approach doesn't seem to be applicable. I tried to google whether someone already solved this but found nothing satisfactory. Perhaps I was asking google wrong question.

To be more precise about **what I need**: Structure capable of storing mutually non-dominating pareto optimal elements. I need to insert elements into the structure and I need to iterate over elements but in no particular order. In my case there won't usually more then 4-5 elements, but sometimes more up to 10-20. Insertions into the bag happen VERY often in my algorithm so I need them to be as fast as possible.

The application is written in C++, but it is probably not really relevant.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** I already had some ideas of my own - arranging elements into some sort of triangular structure, but I am quite unable to formalize that idea.

**Edit2:** Please note that I require, that after each insertion, only mutually non-dominating elements remain in the structure. For example if I have set of non-dominating triples `{(1,2,3), (3, 1, 1)}` and add triple `(3, 3, 3)` I will get set `{(3,3,3)}`.

**Edit3:** To be more clear about dominance of elements - We say, in this particular case, that triple `(a,b,c)` dominates `(e,f,g)` if and only if `a >= e && b >= f && c >= g` and at least one of inequalities is strict - `>`.

Comment: If they don't have to be sorted, why not just put them in a `std::vector` and append new elements?

Comment: +1, you append to the vector, but keep its capacity greater than size, to prevent frequent reallocations. Anyway, you need to profile

Comment: I added a bit of explanation about the dominance of elements inside the set.

Comment: I suspect, you could exploit relations such as: ``if t2 dominates t3 and t1 dominates t2 then t1 dominates t3``...or not. But maybe there is another relation next to dominant which would allow to define an order, which then would allow to find the position of the new triplet in the set of triplets in a better than O(n) way.

Comment: [Kernel Linked Lists](https://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/) could help you if you really need it (each element will be in 3 lists, sorted by the respective value). The implementation allows to check an element and continue the list traversal with any of the lists. But the overhead will probably neglect the advantage for ~20 elements.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? That is relevant. Are you solving a graph search problem? Then, you could take advantage of the lexicographic order of exploring Pareto paths to speed up the search.

Comment: Well sort of. I am working on routing in public transport network. If I simplify  a bit, I could say that for each station I store set of pareto-optimal journeys. While the criteria are target arrival, number of transfers and some third thing which is quite complex to explain.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that new elements are not dominated by solutions already in the set?

Answer (score 1):

You could e.g. order them by their norm (like `a*a + b*b + c*c`), then you need only check the elements with a bigger norm if they dominate the new element and check only the elements with a smaller norm, if they are dominated by the new element.

However, I'm not sure if ordering of your elements is of particular value, if you only have so few of them to begin with. Maintaining that order (whatever it is) comes with its own overhead and might very well outweigh any benefits you get in terms of algorithmic complexity. In particular, I'd refrain from anything, that involves dynamic per-element allocation and deallocation, like `std::list` or `std::map` with standard allocators. Even a heap on an array might not bring a noticeable advantage.

I'd probably just use a plain, unsorted `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Element> frontier;
void insert(const Element& newElement) {
    if (std::none_of(frontier.begin(), frontier.end(),  [&](const auto& e) {return dominates(e, newElement); })) {
        frontier.erase(std::remove_if(frontier.begin(), frontier.end(), [&](const auto& e) {return dominates(newElement, e); }),frontier.end());
        frontier.push_back(newElement);     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The trival approach first, so we can see what we try to improve and validate, that this answer actually is relevant to the problem.

```
// Taken from the question and translated.
// Is the dominance condition.
let x_doms_y x y =
    let (a,b,c) = x
    let (e,f,g) = y
    a >= e && b >= f && c >= g &&
    (a > e || b > f || c > g)
```

The Naive approach would require O(n) tests, in order to filter out the existing elements in the data set, which are dominated by the new item to be added.
The following shows the naive O(n) solution, which subsequently we try to improve.

```
type Triplet = int * int * int
type TripletSet = Triplet list

module Naive =
    let insert (t : Triplet) (tset : TripletSet) : TripletSet =
        t :: (tset|> List.filter (fun u -> not (x_doms_y t u)))
```

Starting with an empty list, then subsequently adding one triplet after the next yields:

```
let foo =
[] |> show
|> Naive.insert (1,2,3) |> show
|> Naive.insert (3,1,1) |> show
|> Naive.insert (3,3,3) |> show

> []
  [(1, 2, 3)]
  [(3, 1, 1); (1, 2, 3)]
  [(3, 3, 3)]
```

This appears to meet the expectations.

To improve the speed, next to insertion cost to the chosen data structure, which
shall not be considered here, but which can be relevant, we try to get the number of dominance comparisons reduced to a value < n. On Average, at least.

The problem can be interpreted in a geometric sense. the triplet, e.g. `1,2,3` can be seen as a vector from one end of a cube, which is located at `0,0,0` to its diagonal corner.

Can a cube with smaller volume ever dominate a larger cube? The answer is no.
We can show this by analogy on a 1-dimensional equivalent. If x < y, x cannot dominate y because to dominate, it should hold `x >= y && X > y`.

A similar equivalence can be conceived for 2 dimensions. And it holds in the same sense for our triplet.

Now, we narrowed our search space. Those items in the existing set, which have a smaller volume than the new triplet can be but need not be dominated by the new triplet. Those which have a higher volume than the new triplet cannot be dominated.

Hence, an improved approach would be:

- let qset be the sorted sequence of quadlets, already inserted.
- Let vt be the volume of the new triplet t : (a,b,c). vt = a * b * c
- let qt = (vt,a,b,c)
- Use binary search to find the index pos in qset, by volume.
- All quadlets left of pos (with v < vt) are candidates for filtering.
- All quadlets to the right of pos cannot be dominated as they are bigger.
- So, now, we only have to apply the naive approach to the sub-set qset[0..pos-1]. If the values inserted are random regarding this relation, on average, we only have to filter n/2 where n is the size of qset.
- Insert qt at pos into the qset and return qset.

Comment: I will have to validate this approach in my specific case, but it seems to be very likely good-enough solution at least. Thank you!

Comment: Have you thought about the performance of an actual implementation of this? The OP is talking about ~5 and up 20 elements at most. *"To improve the speed, next to insertion cost to the chosen data structure, which shall not be considered here, but which can be relevant, "*. That is most likely THE dominant factor in terms of performance - not a few more comparisons.

Comment: This is why I wrote this passage. If e.g. he used a std::list and did one new() for each node, it would be bad. If he uses std::vector without reserve and inserts, it could result in a realloc... All this answer shows, is that  it is possible to do fewer comparisions for dominance, using the volume (or abs volume, if he also can have negative values)...

Comment: No argument there - that's why I mentioned the norm (which is the same idea) in my answer too. My point is, that those two considerations (cost of inserting elements and number of comparisons) are not orthogonal and I'm wondering if the improvement in one is worth the worsening in the other.

Comment: To comment on which container will I use - We have custom made implementation of small vector since statistically the number of elements is mostly up to 4. And also to comment why do I want to optimize it so much in the first place - it is at the very core of the algorithm.

Comment: @Jendas For a optimized container, if you are sure, there will never be more than 32, you could try to get rid of moving the items in the container. Maintain a bitmask, each bit indicating which container slot is in use. If you remove items, clear the bit in the mask and add new element to a free slot. I doubt, it can get any faster. ``bsf, bsr``instructions might come in handy for finding rightmost and leftmost used slot in your array of capacity 32.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not rely on that since it can be false in some cases.

Comment: You should have data to inquire. Run a test, finding max length. And do some histogram on how often it happens. If more than 32 is a rarely occuring edge case, you could still use a optimized version and a criterion to fall back to a conservative mode of operation for the corner case. On average, it then still is much faster. Just as a cache often helps, while it is possible that it is actually obstructive.

Answer (score 1):

A first thought might be to somehow use a `std::set` with a compare function that returns whether one element is Pareto-dominated by the other. But because (in C++ at least) element equivalence is determined from comparing the elements reflexively, that would mean element pairs that have no domination relationship would be considered equivalent, so you wouldn't be able to add them to the set. One way might be to use a `multiset`, and then remove all the "smaller" elements first before adding a new one. But I suspect complexity will not be better than in a `vector`, considering that all the elements will be "equivalent" every time you look for the dominated ones.

Anyway, I just wanted to point out that using the Pareto-dominance as the compare function straight into a `set` does not work. The really best solution probably requires more specialized data structures. Having a way to quickly check dominance on each dimension quickly really seems like the way to go in your case, as you have apparently been doing at first for only two dimensions. You have an index for each dimension, to speed up the check. Then for the element you can have a reverse index to allow you to quickly remove it. But that shouldn't be necessary if most of the time you are just making checks instead of modifying the set.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you are looking for a suitable [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) for triplets of integers. However it is unclear why you would like to store the [Pareto frontier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency#Pareto_frontier) in a sorted manner, as you state you would like to iterate *in no particular order*. Perhaps a `set` (which is implemented in the standard library) is already sufficient.

Comment: Perhaps mentioning my original implementation was a bit misleading. I used the ordering to optimize insertion into the structure. Crucial is the fact, that after each insertion i require that only mutually non-dominating elements remain in the structure.

Comment: I see; you were using the sorting to implement the removal of dominated elements more efficiently? Perhaps it would help if you included the actual dominance relation in your question.

Comment: Inserting small elements in a set is pretty inefficient (at least witht the standard allocator), as each insertion requires a dynamic memory allocation. With 5-20 elements I wouldn't worry about asymptotic computational complexity.

Comment: Yes exactly. I edited my question. Hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Naive solution (C++'ish pseudocode):

We store elements in vector `vec`. Then insertion might look like this:

```
void insert(const auto& e) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        if (e.dominates(vec.at(i))) {
            remove(vec.at(i));
        } else if (vec.at(i).dominates(e)) {
            return;
        }
    }
    vec.append(e);
}
```

This code would have to be more polished to efficiently remove elements, but I suspect this isn't the best we can get since we have to call `dominates` always for every element (if inserted element is not dominated) while in my solution I sort of had to check only up to first dominated already in the set and the rest was nicely eliminated.

Comment: For ~20 elements, I suppose that the method body execution time will be quite comparable in speed to the overhead caused by method invocation. You want optimized data structures when at 10^4, 10^6, 10^8 elements.

Comment: True but I would trust the compiler to inline these calls (profiling necessary). Moreover that is not the problem I am dealing with conceptually.

Comment: If you are dealing with big sets of non-dominated paths, check this paper out: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0305054815001240. It's the state-of-the-art in speeding up dominance checks for multiobjective optimization problems. Under reasonable assumptions, you can reduce 3-dim. vector checks to a single scalar comparison. If you can't access the paper here is the PhD associated (Section 4.2): http://riuma.uma.es/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10630/10204/TD_Pulido_Arrebola.pdf?sequence=3